# YII: Getting getLevel() value from another field (not PK)

Tags: php, yii

I got some stuck while login into team application. Here is the code..
EWebUser.php

```
<?php
class EWebUser extends CWebUser{

protected $_model;

protected function loadUser()
{
    if ( $this->_model === null ) {
        $this->_model = StaffDb::model()->findByPk($this->id);
    }
    return $this->_model;
}

function getLevel()
{
    $user=$this->loadUser();
    if ($user->kdstpeg == 02){
        if(substr($user->kdorg,1,4) == '0000') $level=1;
        else if (substr($user->kdorg,2,3) == '000') $level=2;
        return $level;
    }
    return 100;
}
```

UserIdentity.php

```
<?php

class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    private $_id;

    public function authenticate()
    {
            $username = strtolower($this->username);
            $user = MUser::model()->find('LOWER(username)=?', array($username));
                if($user===null)
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
            else if ($user->pwd!=$this->password)
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
                else
                {
                    $this->_id = $user->oldStaffCode;
                    $this->username = $user->username;
                    $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
                }
        return $this->errorCode == self::ERROR_NONE;
    }

     public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_id;
        }
}
```

and StaffDb.php (one of my model)

```
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

public function tableName()
{
    return 'staffdb';
}

public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('oldStaffCode', 'required'),
        ... array('kdstpeg', 'max'=>2),

        array('...', 'safe'),
        array('oldStaffCode, kdstpeg, ...', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}


public function primaryKey()
{
  return 'oldStaffCode';
}
```

When i'm trying to access this application, the error "Trying to get property of non-object" is shown. Then, i put this code on EWebUser.php `print_r ($user);`in order to see what kind of $user's view. But it didn't have any effect. :(
My question is, did I miss something in that codes? Because in my opinion, all of objects are complete. I hope there's a suggestion to solve this problem. Thanks in advance. :D

Comment: can you put full error stack?

Comment: Do you mean about the clear error statement? The stack that happened is "trying to get property of non-object" in line `if ($user->kdstpeg == 02){`.. do you have any suggestion for me to solve this?

Comment: I mean Yii throws out a lot of stack trace not just a sentence you have put. Thats what I was talking about!

Answer (score 1):

If `$user=$this->loadUser();` doesnt find any model because either the id isnt set or the id isnt found, it will return NULL

so `$user->kdstpeg` will try to get the member kdstpeg of NULL which calls the error.
You need a check to see if `$user !== null`

On a Second note:
[print_r](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) wont show NULL, you better do a [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), that will also tell you the type of the variable you dump

**EDIT**
If you are comparing numbers you should not use **02**, if the value of `$user->kdstpeg` is 02 in your DB, it will be a string, while `$user->kdstpeg == 02` will check agains the integer 2, and will return false, so either you need `(int)$user->kdstpeg === 2` or `$user->kdstpeg === '02'`

Comment: strict comparison would be the best choice: `$user->kdstpeg === '02'`